# resetting mysql workbench root password

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reset the root password for mySQL Workbench since I forgot it.  I was reviewing some online tutorials of how to do this, and they all speak of a "bin" folder.  I went to the program folder, and didn't see a bin folder.  How do I do this?

Comment: This is on Winboze, right? Check in your "C:\mysql" for a "bin" folder

Comment: @hovanessyan "Winboze" ? seriously?

Comment: @droidus Did you find the solution? I have the same problem and I don't have mysql server installed.

Comment: There is no such thing as MySQL Workbench password. Workbench is merely a client tool that connects to a server program, MySQL Server. If the server is in your own computer, you can apply regular [password reset instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). If the server is remote, you'll have to contact its administrator.

Answer (score 7):

## Reset MySQL Root Password from PowerShell

#### 1. Stop the MySQL service and process.

```
spsv mysql*
kill -f -Pro mysqld -ErrorA Ignore
```

#### 2. Create a temporary init file

```
ri C:\temp.txt
ni -t f C:\temp.txt 
ac C:\temp.txt "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('4321') WHERE User='root';"
ac C:\temp.txt "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

#### 3. Get the location of the MySQL defaults-file.

```
$defaultsFile = (gci -r -Path "C:\ProgramData\MySQL" -include my.ini).FullName
```

#### 4. Change dir to MySQL bin.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server*\bin"
```

#### 5. Run mysqld with the password reset.

```
& .\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="$defaultsFile" --init-file="C:\\temp.txt"
```

#### 6. Kill and Restart MySQLD (in a new PowerShell prompt).

```
ps mysqld | kill -f
sasv "MySql*"
```

#### 7. Return to the initial prompt and test

```
& .\mysql -u root -p4321
\q
```

## Notes

1. We cannot do anything until we stop MySql completely.
2. Create this in `C:\`, then add reset password commands; `ri` removes any existing temp.txt file.
3. You can retrieve this path through the Service Control Manager or use `(gwmi win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'mysql*'} | select -First 1).PathName`.
4. The `*` in the path means that we don't have to know our version number.
5. The `&` makes PowerShell run the `exe` like the command line does. Once you run this, PowerShell will appear to hang - that's because it's running the `mysqld` process.
6. We need to kill in another process, because the existing console is busy.
7. Return to the initial console, because it's already at `bin`. After the test, you should see `mysql>`. Use `\q` to quit.

## See Also

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 4):

Reset MySQL root password [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) has cases for Windows and Unix systems, and a "generic" instruction at the end of the document. Hope that helps.

Comment: what is winboze?  mysql workbench 5.2 ce is located in program files (x86).  here is an image of its location, and everythin inside of that folder. http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=5zv5q2l9ikxc8j4

Comment: yeah, but you use MySQL Workbench to connect to a MySQL server - you need the mysql server binaries. What do you have up-one-folder from what you show in your screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

**An easy & fast way ;)**

1- open `Run` or press `win + R`,  then type `services.msc`

2- stop `MySQL80`

3- create a text file named `mysql-init.txt` in the root of `C drive`:

```
C:\mysql-init.txt
```

4- add this content to "mysql-init.txt"

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';
```

5- run this command:

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

6- start `MySQL80` from `services.msc` and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a helpful Video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8_fpBE9deA&ab_channel=CSCORNERSunitaRai

Her solution in summary:

- open and Run or press `win + R`, type -> `services.msc` and stop "`MySQL80`" service.
- create a text file named `mysql-init.txt` in the root of C drive or whereever you want:

> e.g: `C:\mysql-init.txt`

- add the following content to your "`mysql-init.txt`"

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY
> 'change-this-to-your-new-password';

---

Last Step:

Open CMD with Admin rights:

- navigate to "`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`" in CMD

---

> C:\Windows\system32> `cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`

- then Type in the command: `mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --init-file="C:\Users\wow\Desktop\mysql-init.txt"`

e.g:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin> mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --init-file="C:\mysql-init.txt" --console
```

---

Now Without closing the cmd window, you can try to connect to your SQL server befor restarting your "`MySQL80`" service.

- search in your windows Searchbar for "`MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client`" and start it.
- enter your newly created password to check if it worked or not. If it works, Great! If not then just watch the Youtube Video above.

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you are on Windows 7 like me you will find the MySQL executables here: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin . I used mysqld.exe, because mysqld-nt.exe doesn't exist anymore in newer versions of MySQL.

After following the instructions in the documentation you should have a command similar to this: 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my-medium.ini" --init-file=C:\mysql-initRootPass.txt

Note: make sure you run the CMD.exe as Administrator. For the most part that fixed it for me.